# Get distance walked using Google fit Recording_API in android

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am making a fitness app in which I need to get the steps count and distance moved by user. For that I am using Google fit RECORDING_API by subscribing to steps count and distance, I successfully got the steps count but not able to get the distance. Here is my code

```
Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(googleApiClient, DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
                        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(Status status) {
                                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                    if (status.getStatusCode() == FitnessStatusCodes.SUCCESS_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED) {
                                        Log.e( "RecordingAPI", "Already subscribed to get Distance Recording API");
                                    } else {
                                        Log.e("RecordingAPI", "Subscribed to get distance using Recording API");
                                    }
                                }
                                new FetchDistanceAsync().execute();
                            }
                        });




private class FetchDistanceAsync extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Float>{
    @Override
    protected Float doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        float distance = 0;
        PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(googleApiClient, DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA);
        DailyTotalResult totalResult = result.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (totalResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            DataSet totalSet = totalResult.getTotal();
            if (totalSet != null) {
                distance = totalSet.isEmpty() ? 0 : totalSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_DISTANCE).asFloat();
            }
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem getting the calories.");
        }
        return distance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Float aLong) {
        super.onPostExecute(aLong);
        float distance = aLong/1000;
        double dis = Math.round(distance * 100.0) / 100.0;
        tvKilometer.setText(String.valueOf(dis));
    }
}
```

The distance is returning me 0. Actually I moved 184 steps but still the distance is returning value 0. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Can someone please help.

Comment: You may check the [`com.google.distance.delta`](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#data_types_for_instantaneous_readings) data type which returns the distance covered since the last reading. Also based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783825/google-fit-api-get-distance-from-google-fit), make sure that you have added the following scope when you instantiate `GoogleApiClient.Builder`: `.addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))`.