# Distance with Google Fit API

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Google fit API gives the steps count from the history as well. How can I get distance history from the API?

more info: https://developers.google.com/fit/faq

```
 FitnessOptions fitnessOptions =
            FitnessOptions.builder()
                    .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
                    .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                    .build();

    if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions)) {
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                this,
                REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE,
                GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
                fitnessOptions);
    } else {
        subscribe();
    }

public void subscribe() {
    // To create a subscription, invoke the Recording API. As soon as the subscription is
    // active, fitness data will start recording.
    Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .subscribe(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
            .addOnCompleteListener(
                    new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
                            } else {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.", task.getException());
                            }
                        }
                    });
}
```

Following code reads the current daily step total, computed from midnight of the current day on the device's
current timezone.

```
private void readData() {
    Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .readDailyTotal(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                    new OnSuccessListener<DataSet>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DataSet dataSet) {
                            long total =
                                    dataSet.isEmpty()
                                            ? 0
                                            : dataSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();
                                Log.i(TAG, "Total steps: " + total);



                        }
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(
                    new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem getting the step count.", e);
                        }
                    });
}
```

So in spite of total steps, I need to get the distance in kilometers.

Your help can be proven to big favour for us.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to read DataType documentation to find right  DataType.TYPE_XXXXXX ?

Comment: @Selvin, yes, but there is no instruction to get kilometer from history API

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783825/google-fit-api-get-distance-from-google-fit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get total distance daily :

```
private void readHistoryData() {
    // Invoke the History API to fetch the data with the query
    Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
        .readDailyTotal(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataSet>() {
             @Override
             public void onSuccess(DataSet dataSet) {
                dumpDataSet(dataSet);
            }
        });
}
```

Be sure current day has fitness data with distance

Comment: what if I want another daydistance?